# Is there a module to create incentivized social media marketing conditionals?

Tags: 7, commerce

Currently I'm looking to implement a feature where a user can facebook/twitter share a link or a snippet of text to their social media network and then have drupal capture that feedback to see if they did it or not. From there I want to be able to give them a % discount when purchasing something from my site which is running drupal 7 commerce. Is there something like this built already? if not how would one go about doing this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a module that does this.

You're going to have to be pretty familiar with Drupal, Commerce, PHP and the APIs of the platforms you'd like to use.

Because this question is so huge, it's not a good fit for this forum.  This forum is only for asking direct questions, with clearcut answers.